# Chrome and Skype are broken after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, google-chrome, skype

I am very newby on ubuntu so I will try to explain my problem in a silly way :)

I had 12.04 untill today in my second partition and I decided to run it. Then I upgrade it to 14.04 (just finished). However, when I try to run skype it returned me error. When I check details, I saw the "not installed" message. But I was able to use it before. And just before the upgrading I was surfing with chrome. Now I can't run it either. I click it and nothing happens. I checked the "installed apps" in the software center, I can't see both of them. But, for instance, I still have my .skype directory under the /home. Even I see the diretory with my skype username out there.

Maybe there are also another apps in the same situation. So,
What is going on? What I have to do? Give me some cool console commands :p

EDIT: I also see these messages when I use `sudo apt-get ....` command. (I tried to translate it from my own language:

```
N: In the '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' directory 'google-chrome.list.save' file is an invalid file extension, so it is ignored.
N: In the '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' directory 'ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-precise.list.distUpgrade'  file is an invalid file extension, so it is ignored.
N: In the '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' directory 'google-chrome.list.distUpgrade' file is an invalid file extension, so it is ignored.
N: In the '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' directory 'google-chrome.list.save'  file is an invalid file extension, so it is ignored.
N: In the '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' directory 'ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-precise.list.distUpgrade'  file is an invalid file extension, so it is ignored.
N: ın the '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' directory 'google-chrome.list.distUpgrade'  file is an invalid file extension, so it is ignored.
```

And this, I got this after trying Skype again:

```
E: 'skype:i386' packet has no candidate version, so candidate version cannot be chosen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use console to run the app. 
There should be more verbose error.

For skype - you may need remove ~/.Skype (rename )

Check /etc/apt/sources.list for uncommented:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

And reinstall skype from the ubuntu partner repo:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install skype
```

For google chrome I use following:

```
wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - && echo deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main|sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && echo deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list && sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Thanks. But like I said. I am very newby. How can I run the app via console?

Comment: What DE do you use? Try to type **konsole** or **console** or **xterm** to run a console. KDE accepts Alt-F2 to run any.

Comment: ok, I did what you said. for 1st: "deb invalid command. did u mean deb3?" 2nd: "skype:i386 is already newest version" and 3rd: "google-chrome-stable is already newest version" (I tried to translate from my own language". I think nothing happend...

Comment: is there any repair command?

Comment: Hey, I edited my first post. Can you check it again?

Comment: To get english output use:
    export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
Get rid of wrong files at /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
.save and .distUpgrade are left from dist-upgrade
Have you tried:
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
or
    sudo do-release-upgrade

Comment: Please do: sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

Comment: Skype is a i386 app and will require i386 libs.

Comment: If your upgrade failed some where. You may need to do: sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20787/discussion-between-maximkostrikin-and-whocares).